# Jquery not firing in firefox, but works in IE and Edge

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Jquery function is not triggering in firefox, when i press bootstrap link in nav menu, it triggers Jquery function to display simple alert.

```
$(document).on('click', '.dropdown-item', function (event) { alert("Test click event."); });
```

Work in Edge and IE, but I can't get it to work in Firefox. I also had look at previous topics, regarding same issue, still doesnt work in Firefox. I am working in visual studio with ASP.NET and bootstrap 4 CSS.

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <!-- MENU SECTION -->
    <div class="container-fluid bg-success p-md-2 text-white border-bottom border-warning">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm">

                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="Index.html">
                        <img src="img/LOGO%20MIMO%20V1.png" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm text-right">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-success navbar-dark">
                        <!-- Links -->
                        <ul class="navbar-nav">
                            <li class="nav-item active pl-md-4">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="About.aspx">About</a>
                            </li>
                            <!-- Dropdown -->
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown pl-md-4">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    Services
                                </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu bg-success">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="Maintenance.aspx">Maintenance</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="Verification.aspx">Verification</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="Audits.aspx">Audits</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="Uncertainty.aspx">Uncertainty</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="Mismeasurements.aspx">Mismeasurements</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="VBADevelopment.aspx">VBA Development</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item pl-md-4">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="Calculations.aspx">Calculations</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item pl-md-4">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="Contact.aspx">Contact</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Any errors in browser dev tools console? Very unusual to see anything that is *"works in IE"* not FF or chrome. The opposite has been a plague to developers for many years

Comment: @charlietfl, just this GEThttps://localhost:44314/favicon.ico

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$(".dropdown-item").on('click', function (event) { alert("Test click event."); });`?

Comment: @Mech OP is using delegated version which should work just fine cross browser

Comment: Double check that scripts are all loading is my only suggestion

Comment: @Mech, it's not working in any browser. Could be the qoutations mark like " and '?

Comment: Mech's version only works when elements exist on page load and if code is after the elements or inside `$(function(){ /* code here*/})`. Try wrapping your code in that and see what happens

Comment: @charlietfl, the jquery function is not contained on the master page, but is inside js script file. And the JS file is referenced on the master page head section.

Comment: Well if a script file loads before elements it queries for it won't find them unless it uses a load event which is what that snippet does

Comment: It is working now in firefox, and I still dont understand why. This happens quite frequnetly, when I make a change and then I test it right after, in IE and Edge it works immediately, but never with firefox. I am using visual studio 2019.

Comment: @Milenko, it is because scripts are also cache by the browser. If you change something on the javascripts and the update didn't change it behavior try to clean the cache of your browser.